# Mask text, but still allow users to copy it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am sending sensitive information to my users that I would like them to be able to copy (for pasting elsewhere) but not see directly.

There are a few approaches I have considered, and I am stuck on all of them.

1. Populate an password box with the data, but this doesn't allow
   them to copy the text.
2. Make the text color the same as the background color. However, I
       am afraid that my users will not even know that there is text to
       copy. They will just sit there and go "I don't see a any text!" Even
       if I do point out very explicitly what they are supposed to do, then
       the text will still be visible when it is selected.
3. Create some kind of on_copy event that will pass the text when a
       user copies the asterisks. I know how to use jQuery's bind() to
       detect a copy, but I have not found a way to change what actually
       gets copied.
4. Last and least: Something fancy with javascript and clipboard
       management. I really don't want to go there as it would require
       flash.

Comment: Why would you ever "like them to be able to copy (for pasting elsewhere) but not see directly"???

Comment: Is this a security issue.  If a user copies the text, they can just paste to notepad and see it, right?

Comment: They are meant to copy the text and paste it into a password field on another site. It's their data. They can put it into a text editor if they would like, but they would have no reason to.

Comment: @SidharthMudgal to prevent others that look over the shoulder of the user to see the 'sensitive information', I'd guess. Like sending a password with a POST request rather than a GET request, because you don't want to show your password in the URL to someone who just accidentally passes by.

Comment: Why not just have a "show in plain text" checkbox that toggles between displaying as input type=password and normal input? I've seen that on some user interfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this... you make a `div` or `input` containing the "hidden" text with `opacity 0.001`, `focus()` it and set it's selection on the whole content (which should be the text you want the person to copy) via javascript and somehow inform the user to press `Ctrl+C` to copy the data (possibly with an javascript popup-like event that stays there for a few seconds for the user to read it).

Comment: Opacity! Just the kind of idea that I was looking for. I am going to also make it select the text whenever they click in the box, and maybe try to find a way to add some more visual feedback so that they know what is selected. This will get me going in a direction that works.